# Why do I keep Getting can't init this card about sending sms via gsm in java

Tags: java, serial-port

First of all, I have such a issue here first I got a nullPointerException when trying to connect to com port 12, I have tried this several different ways, first by just selecting the port and going after it secondly by searching for the port and trying it. The second time around I kept getting this 32 bit 64 bit mismatch exception for my RXTX lib so I fixed that and then came up with this error
[image]

So, after this error I checked my modem mode(Huawei e3531) that I've used and switched it into GSM mode from WCDMA. What should I do now? Here's my code:
This is my Connect class

```
    package sendMessage;

import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.CommPortOwnershipListener;
import gnu.io.PortInUseException;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Connect implements SerialPortEventListener,
        CommPortOwnershipListener
{

    static String comPort = ""; // This COM Port must be connect with GSM Modem or your mobile phone
    private CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
    private Enumeration<?> portList;
    private InputStream inputStream = null;
    private OutputStream outputStream = null;
    private SerialPort serialPort;

    public Connect(String comm)
    {

        Connect.comPort = comm;
    }

    public boolean init()
    {
        portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        while (portList.hasMoreElements())
        {
            portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
            System.out.println(portId);
            if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
            {
                if (portId.getName().equals(comPort))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void checkStatus()
    {
        send("AT+CREG?\r\n");
    }


    public void send(String cmd)
    {
        try
        {

            outputStream.write(cmd.getBytes());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {
        send("AT+CMGF=1\r");
        send("AT+CMGS=\"" + phoneNumber + "\"\r\n");
        send(message + '\032');
    }


    public void connect() throws NullPointerException, PortInUseException
    {
        if (portId != null)
        {
            try
            {
                portId.addPortOwnershipListener(this);
                serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("MobileGateWay", 2000);
            }
            catch (PortInUseException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try
            {
                inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
                outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
            }

            try
            {

                serialPort.addEventListener(this);
                serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
            }
            catch (TooManyListenersException e)
            {
            }

            send("ATZ\r\n");

        }
        else
        {
            throw new NullPointerException("COM Port not found!!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent serialPortEvent)
    {
        switch (serialPortEvent.getEventType())
        {
            case SerialPortEvent.BI:
            case SerialPortEvent.OE:
            case SerialPortEvent.FE:
            case SerialPortEvent.PE:
            case SerialPortEvent.CD:
            case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
            case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
            case SerialPortEvent.RI:
            case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
            case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:

                byte[] readBuffer = new byte[2048];
                try
                {
                    while (inputStream.available() > 0)
                    {
                        int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
                    }
//print response message
                    System.out.print(new String(readBuffer));
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void ownershipChange(int type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case CommPortOwnershipListener.PORT_UNOWNED:
                System.out.println(portId.getName() + ": PORT_UNOWNED");
                break;
            case CommPortOwnershipListener.PORT_OWNED:
                System.out.println(portId.getName() + ": PORT_OWNED");
                break;
            case CommPortOwnershipListener.PORT_OWNERSHIP_REQUESTED:
                System.out.println(portId.getName() + ": PORT_INUSED");
                break;
        }

    }

}
```

This is my main class:

```
package sendMessage;

import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

public class GUIToSendMessage extends Frame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextField jTextField_mobiNo = null;
    private JLabel jLabel_mobno = null;
    private JButton jButton_send = null;
    private JPanel jPanel_contents = null;
    private JLabel jLabel_msg = null;
    private JTextField jTextField_message = null;
    /**
     * This is the default constructor
     */
    public GUIToSendMessage() {
        super();
        initialize();
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new GUIToSendMessage().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes this
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private void initialize() {
        jLabel_mobno = new JLabel();
        jLabel_mobno.setText("Mobile No");
        jLabel_mobno.setBounds(new Rectangle(28, 74, 74, 16));
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(341, 348);
        this.setTitle("Send Message");

        this.add(getJPanel_contents(), null);
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes jTextField_mobiNo
     *
     * @return javax.swing.JTextField
     */
    private JTextField getJTextField_mobiNo() {
        if (jTextField_mobiNo == null) {
            jTextField_mobiNo = new JTextField();
            jTextField_mobiNo.setBounds(new Rectangle(135, 75, 143, 20));
        }
        return jTextField_mobiNo;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes jButton_send
     *
     * @return javax.swing.JButton
     */
    private JButton getJButton_send() {
        if (jButton_send == null) {
            jButton_send = new JButton();
            jButton_send.setText("Send");
            jButton_send.setBackground(Color.white);
            jButton_send.setBounds(new Rectangle(124, 227, 78, 32));
            jButton_send.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                    String mobiNo = jTextField_mobiNo.getText();
                    String message =jTextField_message.getText();

                    Connect gsm = new Connect("COM12");
                    if (gsm.init())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            gsm.connect();
                            gsm.checkStatus();
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            gsm.sendMessage(mobiNo, message);

                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            //gsm.hangup();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Can't init this card");
                    } // TODO Auto-generated Event stub actionPerformed()
                }
            });
            jButton_send.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("actionPerformed()"); // TODO Auto-generated Event stub actionPerformed()
                }
            });
        }
        return jButton_send;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes jPanel_contents
     *
     * @return javax.swing.JPanel
     */
    private JPanel getJPanel_contents() {
        if (jPanel_contents == null) {
            jLabel_msg = new JLabel();
            jLabel_msg.setBounds(new Rectangle(37, 129, 58, 16));
            jLabel_msg.setText("Message");
            jPanel_contents = new JPanel();
            jPanel_contents.setLayout(null);
            jPanel_contents.setBounds(new Rectangle(9, 31, 330, 315));
            jPanel_contents.setBackground(new Color(204, 204, 255));
            jPanel_contents.add(getJButton_send(), null);
            jPanel_contents.add(getJTextField_mobiNo(), null);
            jPanel_contents.add(jLabel_mobno, null);
            jPanel_contents.add(jLabel_msg, null);
            jPanel_contents.add(getJTextField_message(), null);
        }
        return jPanel_contents;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes jTextField_message
     *
     * @return javax.swing.JTextField
     */
    private JTextField getJTextField_message() {
        if (jTextField_message == null) {
            jTextField_message = new JTextField();
            jTextField_message.setBounds(new Rectangle(131, 125, 151, 20));
        }
        return jTextField_message;
    }

}
```

I have asked this question before but can't seem to get any responses, any suggestion's?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your port name "COM12" is the right one? What if you replace `System.out.println(portId);` with `System.out.println(portId.getName());` and run your program again, to check all the serial port names on your system

Comment: @lulian Dogariu the same error

Comment: What port names do you see printed out?

Comment: @Iulian Dogariu , yeah I am sure my port name is COM12, I send sms using Hyperterminal through AT commands to my number, but through my java code I am getting this error

Comment: gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier@1a11cfa4
gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier@45526de0
gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier@42761002

Comment: that is the output when you call `System.out.println(portId);`. What is the output you see when you call `System.out.println(portId.getName());` ?

Comment: I did as you said, I added System.out.println(portId.getName()); but it gives me gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier@521ba04f
gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier@78c59368
gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier@1a39c998 again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I solved my problem, I just installed 32 bit jdk instead of 64 bit jdk and errors disappeared, thanks for comments